# Laravel 5.3 installation Error

Tags: laravel, composer-php, laravel-5.3

I have just install xampp with PHP version 7 and install composer too. when i type this in composer `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog` it gives following errors.How can i solve it

```
E:\xampp\htdocs>composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog
You are running Composer with SSL/TLS protection disabled.


  [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
  The "http://packagist.org/p/provider-2016-04%245bb94436a929d80601958ea5367e
  6b3d5111776068c6d8355f4234987de86504.json" file could not be downloaded (HT
  TP/1.1 302 Found)


create-project [-s|--stability STABILITY] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--repository REPOSITORY] [--repository-url REPOSITORY-URL] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no-secure-http] [--keep-vcs] [--no-install] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] [<package>] [<directory>] [<version>]
```

Comment: https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/5656

Answer (score 1):

It's unsecure and not recommended for your Server but for local PC you can run the command.

Run command:

```
composer config -g -- disable-tls true
```

and then re run `composer` it will works

If you don't want to enable unsecure layer in your machine/server, then setup your php to enable openssl and it also works. Make sure the PHP Openssl extension has be installed and enable it on php.ini file.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, The reason was PHP version, My PHP version was 5.6 and I was trying to create a project in Laravel 5.5.

So, I run 
**composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog "5.4.*"**

the project created successfully.